# 405 Method Not Allowed: PUT http://localhost:3030/dataset/data?default

Tags: apache, http, sparql, semantic-web, fuseki

I am trying to import some RDF triples into my datastore. I use the s-put script inorder to do this. But when i try to execute the script, I get an error :

The error reads :

```
405 Method Not Allowed: PUT http://localhost:3030/dataset/data?default
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you post the text please?  Not everyone has images enabled, and even if they do, that's rather small print.

Comment: I am sorry. I have edited the question. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a read-only endpoint. Add "--update" to the Fuseki server command line.

Comment: After many hours of figuring it out, I found out the answer. And I log in here, to see the same exact answer. Anyways thank you for answering my question. To others struggling on similar queries, you can use the above answer. Simply add `fuseki-server --update --desc tdb.ttl /dataset`

Comment: @KripaJayakumar We have made a slight change to Fuseki so that in future releases it will print a brief "Running in read-only mode" as part of the start up logging.  There are plenty of cases where read only mode is the desired behaviour so it will remain the default

Answer (score 0):

This error can mean many things. In case you were dealing with an external server (i.e. not `localhost`), this error may appear if your proxy was refused, for instance.